# Issue with "Call to member function on non-object"

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm not seeing the issue here...

Error:  "Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\In Progress\mtg\index.php on line 64"

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO `" . $database . "`.`users` VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, 0);");
    echo $mysqli -> error;
$stmt -> bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> close();
```

This is the offending block of code and the lines around it. The only thing I can think is that maybe $mysqli isn't being correctly defined in this one instance? $mysqli and $database are defined in a required file and all other functions that reference them for prepared statements work fine.

Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$stmt` is probably undefined because the previous line (`prepare`) failed.
It's basically calling `bind_param()` on a failed prepared statement, which happens to be an error or something.

Comment: Any advice on how to further diagnose the problem if the failed prepare is the source? It doesn't generate any errors other than what's posted.

Comment: I haven't been able to find out exactly why, but put `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)` before your `$stmt` declaration. It may help to identify what is wrong with it.

Comment: Ah! That brought to my attention the stupid mistake I made that I shall not disclose here -_-. Thank you!